# recursive calls in Javascript API (Promises)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, async-await, promise

I am trying to fetch data from one MongoDB collection and with that result, I am passing that value into another function to get the data from GridFS files for same id.

```
router.get('/employee/:id', async(req,res) =>{
    let gID = req.params.id;
    var getUser = await User.find({id:gID});
    //console.log(res);
    
    console.log(getUser);
    if(getUser){
        try{
            
            gfs.files.find({objectID:getUser.id}).toArray(async (err, files) => {
                if (!files || files.length === 0) {
                    res.send({
                        message: "No User Found",
                      });
                } else {
                    
                    res.send({
                        message: "data fetched",
                        data: getUser,
                        image: files
                      });
                }
            });
        }catch(err){
            res.send({
                message:err.code,
                data:err
            });
        }
    }else{
        res.send({
            message:"error in getting the data",
        });
    }
    
})
```

I tried of this but I am not able to get the expected result, I am getting the user information from getUser but I am not able to fetch the file tagged with that user from GridFS. Can anyone tell me where I am lagging and how could I correct this.

Comment: cant you just use the id from the url params like this directly? gfs.files.find(gId}). or is the userId not the same as you pass in the url params?

Comment: no, I cant sent the gID directly in the gfs.files.find. `var getUser = await User.find({id:gID})` form this I need to get a key that need to be send to gfs.files.find as parameter. while doing `console.log(getUsers)` I am getting the whole resultant object but while doing `console.log(getUsers.id)`  it is giving me undefined as result. getUsers.id is just an example, I need to send some other parameter which I will be getting from getUser response.

Comment: Three questions: (1) You speak of "recursive", but I cannot see any recursion in your code. What do you mean? (2) You say you are "not able to fetch from `gfs`", what behavior do you observe? (3) `gfs.files.find({getUser.id})` is equivalent to `gfs.files.find(getUser.id)`, why the extra braces?

Comment: 1. By recursive I mean output of one into another, here output of getUsers needs to passed to `gfs.files.find(getUser.id)` 2. gfs is not giving the expected output, I am getting all files data not the specific one. 3. its a typo error, supposed to be `gfs.files.find({objectId:getUser.id})`

Comment: Never used GridFS but from looking at the documentation, I have string doubts that `{objectId:getUser.id}` is a correct filter. It's probably `{_id:getUser.id}` instead.

Comment: But still, I am getting undefined for getUser.id, where as getting the correct output for getUser